# In physics, when should one use and not use calculus?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, phase-transition, calculus, surface-tension

> Assume that a drop of liquid evaporates by decrease in its surface energy, so that its temperature remains unchanged. What should be the minimum radius of the drop for this to be possible? The surface tension is $T$, density of liquid is $\rho$, and $L$ is its latent heat of vaporization.

Clearly when whatever you’re trying to find out has a varying quantity in it, calculus is required. However in some cases if we know the data about initial and final positions we can use that without including calculus, like energy conservation when acceleration due to gravity is varying with height from surface of Earth.
In the attached question, I tried using the initial state (when the drop just starts evaporating) and the final state (when the drop has completely evaporated) in my answer. Also, the given latent heat of vaporization per mass is $L$.
Let’s suppose that the required radius is $r$ and that the drop is spherical.
\begin{align}
\text{Surface energy}
&= \text{Surface tension} \times \text{surface area of drop}\\
&=T(4\pi{r}^{2}) \, .
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\text{Heat required to evaporate}
&= L \times \text{mass of drop} \\
&= L \left(\frac{4\pi r^3}{3} \right) \rho \, .
\end{align}

Equating the above, we get $r=3T/L\rho$ which is incorrect.
If we use calculus though, by decreasing radius of drop by dx, we get the correct answer. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Here's a classic example of an error due to improper handling of infinitesimal processes & limits: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staircase_paradox

Comment: When you, or somebody else, have already done the integral, you don't have to do it again. The second equation for example is the solved volume integral of $L(x,y,x)\rho(x,y,z)dV$ over a spherical volume of radius r for constant $L, \rho$

Comment: @PM2Ring also reminds me of 3blue1brown's [video](https://youtu.be/VYQVlVoWoPY?si=e_yPZFC7gRzLJQN7) about how pi = 4.  [short teaser here](https://youtube.com/shorts/tjIOqIr80ns?si=RlmfWuJ0gj1TA9Di)

Comment: Truly a JEE moment

Comment: @trystwithfreedom how’d you know

Comment: Brother I went through this all experience some years back, I know how this runs lol @Dumbperson

Comment: I believe It's fair to say that you always use calculus in physics. Anything formula that doesn't involve calculus is an approximation of some sort

Answer (score 14):

You equate the wrong things in the version without $dx$. Namely, you equate the total surface energy of the drop at radius $r$ with the energy to evaporate the entire drop at radius $r$.

But what shows whether the process happens spontaneously or not, is what happens in the next small time step. Even if the entire process would be energetically favourable, there may still be a so called kinetic barrier since turning the whole drop into gas at the same time does not happen, but evaporation happens layer for layer at the surface.

So to check whether the process happens by itself, you have to compare the energy for evaporating a thin surface layer with the surface energy released by that change (and such discussions of small increments are one of the main uses of calculus in physics – going from $\Delta x$ to $dx$ makes the entire calculation much easier as you can drop all higher powers of $dx$ that occur).

**Addendum regarding the difference to mechanical conservation of energy problems:**

In mechanics, the same problem with a kinetic barrier may occur when just using energy conservation and end states. For example, if you have a particle in on well of a double well potential $V(x) = \alpha x^4 - \beta x^2$ ($\alpha > 0$, $\beta > 0$) with too little kinetic energy to get to the other well, then looking purely at energy conservation, you could come to the conclusion that the end state of the system may be with the particle in the other well, however, that state is kinetically not reachable.

In situations where a simple conservation argument suffices, you know from some other argument that the type of path you consider is *qualitatively* possible. Then you can use the conservation of energy (and momentum, angular momentum, etc.) to get the precise numbers.

Examples of such arguments:

- For collisions you can use energy and momentum conservation for a very small time increment from before to after the collision (and assume that external forces are small compared to the collision forces).
- If there's just a homogeneous gravitational field, a harmonic oscillator potential or no external potential, you know that there are no local maxima of the field, so the conservation laws will suffice to find things like maximal heights, etc.
- When computing speeds at positions from a potential and initial conditions, the solution will break down in the forbidden regions.
- Additional conservation laws may select the correct solution from a set obtained from one conservation law.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding the energy conservation problem(the one with the varying acceleration), that process does not happen simultaneously as well, yet comparison of initial and final states is possible, so what is the difference between the two scenarios that one requires calculus and the other doesn’t?

Comment: I think "whether to use calculus" is not the right question. It's about whether you can use any shortcut, to avoid calculating something the long way. Although often it's true that the shortcut means you can avoid doing calculus. But if you aren't sure that a shortcut is safe/correct, you should always do the full calculation. Then you can check if the shortcut would give the same answer, and try to understand why or why not.

Answer (score 6):

I don't find title and description relate much,

Regarding question in description you are considering heat required to evaporated spherical surface of radius r and you have solved the equations for that, but in question they asked about whole sphere!

If you calculate heat required to perform given process in given constraints for all possible layers(drop of fluid is made up of large number of infinitely thin concentric spheres) ie, starting from layer with radius nearly zero to outermost layer, then you will end up with correct answer.

But isn't it impossible to do it that way?

To help us do similar task when you have to *add infinitesimally small bits* or just *break something into infinitesimally small bits* we have a mathematical tool called **calculus**.

Since most of physics questions (at level of question you presented) involve such treatment, calculus is quite useful.

Comment: I think I’m getting it now. The sum of all the surface energies in this process of evaporation is not necessarily equal to the total surface energy at the start of evaporation, and we need to equate the sum of all surface energies to the latent heat, right? 
Please confirm. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Ah! Best of luck for jee

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment at your specific evaporation question but I can answer the general one. I don't even mean this as a joke.

**"When should we use calculus?" — Whenever it is useful.**

**"When should we not use calculus?" — Whenever it is not useful.**

The underlying truth I try to convey is the following. *Calculus* — essentially the mathematical modeling of space and time sliced in infinitesimally small segments — can *always* be used because it is a very direct modelling of nature through first principles. Macroscopic nature is, if you want, a large analog computing machine for calculus equations. Calculus is, to use a fancy term, an *isomorphism*<sup>1</sup> of nature. The isomorphism goes, of course, both ways: Sometimes, analog computers (i.e., specifically designed nature) are elegant and efficient calculus solvers.

But using calculus for simple problems is usually not useful because the calculus problems have a closed form solution: All "equations" we know, like $v=at$, are solved calculus computations. To calculate the eventual speed difference after some given time has passed at constant acceleration by integrating is overkill; you simply use the formula. But if the acceleration varies you'll need to solve the corresponding integral.

By the way, "useful" is a term with many meanings. I suppose that it can be useful to state any problem in calculus terms; if those yield the correct result the problem has been understood properly on a fundamental level, which is "useful" in its own right.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Using the word somewhat loosely here (the mapping is probably not bijective).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Give that the question ask for a minimum radius, that implies that there is a minimum radius, which means that the volume interior to that radius cannot evaporate through this process, which means that using the volume of the entire sphere must be wrong.

Anthropomorphizing the droplet, the droplet doesn't "know" how much energy it takes to evaporate the entire droplet. Each molecule evaporates separately, and in the moment that it evaporates, the droplet's temperature either decreases or it doesn't. This condition, that the droplet's temperature doesn't decrease, is a "local" property, in that it refers to what's happening moment-to-moment.

The energy it takes to evaporate the *entire* droplet, as opposed to what's evaporating at this moment, has no effect on whether the process happens *at this exact moment*. You could replace the interior of the droplet with something with ten times the latent heat of water, and what happens instantaneously will be unaffected.

The wording of the question is somewhat misleading, however, as it says "assume that the droplet evaporates", which could be interpreted as saying "assume that the entire droplet evaporates" (after all, generally when we say that something happens to something, that means it happens to the whole something, not part of it). It would be more clear if it said "assume that the droplet is evaporating".

Answer (score 0):

I simply use calculus methods when I need to solve problems based on small changes or when there is a curved surfaces or to prove some results.
Like when I have to prove the moment of inertia of an object.
We also have to use it for variable things.

Also, I skip calculus for problems like calculating general results like time taken for an object to slide an inclined plane under various circumstances.

Comment: This is certainly a more straightforward way out, but not necessarily time effective, which is everything for a competitive examination.

Comment: like i will give these exams the next year and my teacher told me to learn the calculus required proofs so that i dont have to do long proofs there (exam time)